# Find a string in a text file and put it in another fle with regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, scripting

The idea is i want to get the ID of a virtual machine through euca-describe-instances and put it in a text file with bash scripting.

The output of the `euca-describe-instances` command is:

```
RESERVATION r-65C341BF  016346531768    my_sec_group
INSTANCE    i-6FA53F18  emi-4AE43EB9    euca-194-   euca-192.euca3.internal running balalala    0m1.medium  2014-02-14T13:29:04.582Z    wiat-c01                monitoring-disabled 100.100.602.156 191.169.98.86       ebs                 hvm                     
BLOCKDEVICE /dev/sda    vol-ABE63A99    2014-02-14T13:29:04.819Z    true
```

I want to take the instance ID, which in this case is i-6FA53F18. I want to do this with regular expressions and the code so far is, and no output, no error nothing:

```
euca-describe-instances | grep 'i-[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}' >> instance_state.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
euca-describe-instances | grep INSTANCE | awk '{print $2}' >> instance_state.txt
```

This assumes `INSTANCE` precedes the `i-6FA53F18`... If `i-6FA53F18` is always in the 2nd row and 2nd column, then you can use just `awk` :

```
euca-describe-instances | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}' >> instance_state.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
euca-describe-instances | grep "INSTANCE" | sed "s/^.*INSTANCE  *\([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/" >> instance_state.txt
```

This does not assume that "INSTANCE" is the first word in the row (although currently, in the given example, it is).

Answer (score 1):

You **don't** need `grep` with `awk`.

```
euca-describe-instances | awk '/INSTANCE/{ print $2 }' >> instance_state.txt
```